# convert string to BigInt dataframe spark scala

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert values into dataframe in which fields are `string` type into `postgresql` database in which field are big `int` type.

I didn't find how to cast them as big `int`.I used before IntegerType I got no problem. But with this dataframe the cast cause me negative integer

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("spark session example").getOrCreate()

  val cabArticleGold = sparkSession.sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:System/maher@//localhost:1521/XE", "dbtable" -> "IPTECH.TMP_ARTCAB")).select("CODEART", "CAB").limit(10)
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
 cabArticleGold.show()
cabArticleGold.withColumn("CAB",'CAB.cast(IntegerType)).foreach(row=>println(row(1)))

232524399
-1613725482
232524423
-1613725465
232524437
-1191331072
3486
-1639094853
232524461
1564177573
```

Any help to use Big Int would be appreciated.I know that `scala` supports Big Int, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For large integer you should use [`LongType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType):

```
cabArticleGold.withColumn("CAB", 'CAB.cast(LongType))
```

or

```
cabArticleGold.withColumn("CAB", 'CAB.cast("long"))
```

You can also use `DecimalType`

```
cabArticleGold.withColumn("CAB", 'CAB.cast(DecimalType(38, 0)))
```

or

```
cabArticleGold.withColumn("CAB", 'CAB.cast("decimal(38, 0)"))
```